# First day with R- Why isnt a regression line showing?

Tags: r

I have a very simple data set of population over time.  I can get a static abline to show horizontally or vertically but nothing shows when I try to do a regression line. My code is below.

```
LinReg <- lm(FL.POP)
plot(FL.POP)
abline(LinReg)
```

[image: plot with no line]

Comment: `lm` needs a _formula_. "FL.POP" is not a formula. Maybe you want `LinReg <- lm(FL.POP~Year)`; `plot(FL.POP~Year, data=my_data)`; `abline(LinReg)`.

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue, but then you did not include the data. With random data I get a line just as expected. What does `print(LinReg)` show? Did you get any error message?

Comment: @Edward - it doesn't need an explicit formula, it uses `DF2formula()` if passed a data frame (first column is response, all others predictors).  OP's model could be ok.

Comment: @H1. His plot suggests only "Year" is a predictor, but it is missing in the _formula_.

Comment: @Edward, `lm(mtcars[,1:2])` is identical to `lm(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars)`. While I agree that the documentation does say the first argument should be a formula, it still works. The inferred to be effectively `column1 ~ .`.

Comment: @r2evans. The plot command won't match the `abline` command unless OP uses a formula version of `plot`, or switches the x and y axis.

Comment: Not true. `plot(mtcars[,1:2]); abline(lm(mtcars[,1:2]))` shows a portion of a line. The fact that it is missing from the OP plot suggests to me that it is off the scale.

Comment: `plot(mtcars[,2:1]); abline(lm(mtcars[,1:2]))` works. So OP has to switch the x and y or use formula method of plot.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you do not use a formula, you have to reverse the order of the variables in the plot:

```
data(iris)
dta <- iris[1:20, 1:2]
LinReg <- lm(dta)
plot(dta[, 2:1])
abline(LinReg)
```

Note that plot(dta) puts the independent variable on the horizontal axis so that the line does not fit on the plot. As the comments suggest it is much better to use an explicit formula to avoid this confusion.

[image: Plot]